# replace span with new data but new jquery call is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a big problem with this situation. I've been looking for this problem for a week and I don't find the answer. If someone knows how can I solve it, I really appreciate. I'm a newby in jQuery.

My problem is simple:

I find and replace what I need to replace but the new data link doesn't call the jQuery function `ej` like for unlike the first like works but when it is replaced for unlike you click unlike and doesn't call the function jQuery.

```
/// like 
$('.like').livequery("click",function(e){
    var getID   =  $(this).attr('id').replace('post_idpl','');
    $.post("2.php?p_idpl="+getID, {             
    }, function(response){
        $('span', 'div.like-head'+getID).html('<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="post_idpl'+getID+'" class="unlike">Unlike</a>');
    });
}); 

/// unlike 
$('.unlike').livequery("click",function(e){
    var getID   =  $(this).attr('id').replace('post_idpl','');
    $.post("3.php?p_idpu="+getID, {
    }, function(response){
        $('span', 'div.like-head'+getID).html('<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="post_idpl'+getID+'" class="like">Like</a>');
    });
}); 
// ]]>
```

Comment: Please post your question in a proper formatted manner.

Comment: I reformatted your code, but it's still a mess to me: e.g., why are all those empty lines in your code and why did you put bit of HTML in it? Oh, and properly encode your URL query parameters, like `<?php echo urlencode($email); ?>`

Comment: @joseph , we can easily find the problem if you can post the code properly

Comment: will the statement 
url: '2.php?ema=<?php echo $email; ?>',
work properly ??

Comment: @Korpel: saw that now :)

Comment: yes, Arihant Nahata  it brings the result good. a href="#" id="121" class="unlike" title="Stop liking this post" style="color: #6B84B4">Unlike</a but this unlike is not working

Comment: Please provide proper description, and proper code the next time. Maybe use http://jsfiddle.net, or http://codepad.org/

Comment: <div class="like-head<?php echo $post_idp;?>">
         <span>
   
   <?php
   if($like_ip_num > 0){?>
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" id="post_idpl<?php echo $post_idp;?>" class="unlike">Unlike</a>
   <?php }else{?>
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" id="post_idpl<?php echo $post_idp;?>" class="like">Like</a>
   <?php }?>
    
   </span> </div>

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you want, but i suspect using `.live('click',function(){...` instead of `.click(function(){...` function may solve you problem, see [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> .live() method is able to affect
>   elements that have not yet been added
>   to the DOM through the use of event
>   delegation: a handler bound to an
>   ancestor element is responsible for
>   events that are triggered on its
>   descendants.

Comment: i tried with this and the same happend...i replace a href="#" id="121" class="like" title="like this post" style="color: #6B84B4">Like</a      for      a href="#" id="121" class="unlike" title="Stop liking this post" style="color: #6B84B4">Unlike</a  only replace once but the new link doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

It is an example of parsing float value. Look for your appropriate function in the jQuery documentation.

```
var val = parseFloat( document.getElementById('your_id_tag').innerHTML );
```

Comment: `parseFloat` nor `innerHTML` is part of jQuery, but of JavaScript. Moreover, what are you trying to fix here? Perhaps it's too hot here, but I don't understand anything of your answer.

Comment: is just a like and unlike like facebook, you click like become unlike, unlike become like. and so on.